# Line-breaks in Exception.Message

Tags: c#, string, exception

I'm extending Exception to implement a setter on the Message property. And this works just fine. But somehow this:

```
CustomException.Message = "Test" + Environment.NewLine + "Test Again";
```

Becomes this:

```
"Test\r\nTest Again"
```

I've also tried this, with no luck:

```
CustomException.Message = @"Test

Test Again";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: \r\n will be converted to new line when you display it by using message box. I couldn't understand what's the problem!

Comment: You are right. Add your comment as an answer so I can accept it. 'Twas a brain-fart on my side :)

Comment: Where you would like to print the message? I.e. on web page, in console,...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\r\n characters will be converted to new line when you display it by using message box or assign it to text box or whenever you use it in interface.

Answer (score 11):

`Environment.NewLine` **IS** `\r\n` (at least on Windows, anyway...)